# Alamofire 4.0, Swift 3 Post params not being passed

Tags: swift3, alamofire, xcode8

When I upgraded to latest everything (Alamo 4, Swift 3 and XC 8) the following stopped posting parameters and I dont have a clue why...

```
let params = ["stripeToken": token.tokenId,
              "name": name,
              "email": email
             ]
    Alamofire.request(requestString, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { (response) in
            if response.result.value is NSNull {
                return
            }
```

Comment: There is definitely an issue with jsonserialization.data .

Comment: Have you fixed this? I tried to suggestions below but still not passing params.

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar issue, I changed encoding from JSONEncoding.default to URLEncoding.httpbody or encoding: URLEncoding.default

```
Alamofire.request(URL, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).responseJSON { response in

    if let data = response.data {
        let json = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        print("Response: \(json)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I have the same issue and finally fixed it. URLEncoding.httpBody didn't work for me... but URLEncoding.default did.

So I changed **JSONEncoding.default** to **URLEncoding.default**.

It's now passing the parameters to the backend.

```
Alamofire.request(loginURL, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything works exactly as it should. Here's a quick example demonstrating that fact.

```
func testPostingJSON() {
    let urlString = "https://httpbin.org/post"

    let params: Parameters = [
        "stripeToken": "token_id",
        "name": "cnoon",
        "email": "cnoon@alamofire.org"
    ]

    let expectation = self.expectation(description: "should work")

    Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in
            if let json = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(json)")
            } else {
                print("Did not receive json")
            }

            expectation.fulfill()
        }

    waitForExpectations(timeout: 5.0, handler: nil)
}
```

Hopefully that example helps you pinpoint the issue. Cheers.

Comment: Your code does not test anything....  It just shows that the .responseJSON does not return an error, it doesn't demonstrate that the parameters have been sent to the server.

Comment: I have stepped through all the code and there is an issue with JSONSerialization.data it returns the size in bytes of the parameters passed to it, which effectively means no parameters have been sent to the server.

Comment: as a result .responseJSON returns without error but the server does not receive the parameters for server side processing. I rectified by using URL encoding.

Comment: @Mark that example demonstrates that the parameters ARE sent to the server. Look at the response. The parameters you post are returned in the payload in the response. My code doesn't "test" anything merely because I figured you would at least run it to see that the data sent up comes back in the response.

Comment: This does not demonstrate anything. Was the parameter received at the backend? Your code doesn't demonstrate that.

Comment: I changed the encoding to make mine work. I'm pretty sure that when I tested I was sending optionals and the test above is using defined string values. When I stepped through the code, JSONSerialization was returning incorrect data.